# List index out of range error when I use if statement (Python)

Tags: python, list, index-error

I have a list,

```py
text_split = [['5', '5', '12\n'], ['1', '1\n'], ['1', '2\n'], ['2', '1\n'], ['2', '3\n'], ['3', '1\n'], ['3', '2\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['4', '2\n'], ['4', '4\n'], ['1', '2\n'], ['2', '3\n'], ['5', '5']]
```

I am using the following for loop to iterate through the list and work out if the first index is 1.

It is coming back with 'IndexError: list index out of range:

```py
for i in range(1, len(text_split)+1, 1):
    if text_split[i][0] == '1':
        print("True")
```

The code works and produces `True` where there is a 1 in the first index, but I can't move on from it due to the error.

I am able to do this in the for loop, without error.

```
print(text_split[6][0])
```

This produces the integer 3, as expected.

Comment: With `len(text_split)+1` eventually `i` will be 13, which is out of range for a list with 13 elements in a language that is zero-indexed. The last element of `text_split` is `text_split[12]`. Python discourages this kind of loop. Just loop over the items: `for item in text_split:` then check `item[0]`.

Comment: The elements in a list are 0 to `len(list) - 1`.

Comment: Do `for i,val in enumerate(text_split):` / `if val[0] == '1':`.

Comment: @TimRoberts, why use `enumerate` when `i` is never used?

Comment: Mmm, they mentioned "where the first index is 1", but I see they meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove +1

```
for i in range(1, len(text_split), 1):
    if text_split[i][0] == '1':
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you iterate up to `len(text_split)+1` and then use that variable `i` to index `text_split` you're accessing the list out of bounds. Remember that lists are indexed starting at *zero*.

Better yet is to avoid `range` all together.

```
for lst in text_split:
  if lst[0] == '1':
    print('True')
```